# select tag name not working while using it in php

Tags: php, html, post

I have a form in html and I am saving it  as search.php:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="search_clicked(); return false;">
    Keyword<input type="text" name="Keyword" id="Keyword" value="XYZ" required/><!-- value is the default name that appears in the text box-->
<br>
    Type
    <select name="sel" id="sel"  class="form-control" onchange="checkcolors(this.value)">
    <option selected value="Users">Users</option>
    <option value="Pages">Pages</option>
    <option value="Events">Events</option>
    <option value="Places">Places</option>
    <option value="Groups">Groups</option>
    </select>

  </form>  

    <div id="loc_dist_displayarea" style="display:none;">
        Location<input type="text" name="Location" value="90007" required/>   Distance(meters)<input type="text" name="distance" value="10000" required/>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Search"/>

       <input type="submit" value="clear" id="clear" onclick="return clearclicked()"/>  

</form>
```

and my php script is in the same file:

```
<div id="body_area" style="display:none">
  <?php
    echo "hi I am searching ";

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
  {

//echo "yes value is selected";
//echo $_POST["Keyword"];
if (isset($_POST['sel'])) {
$selectedval= $_POST["sel"];
echo "$selectedval";
}
//echo $_POST["Location"];

}
echo "no value is selected";

?>
    </div>
```

I am not able to display the $_POST['sel'] while $_POST['Keyword'] is echoed.Please help.

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: I am not able to display the $_POST['sel'] while $_POST['Keyword'] is echoed

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you arent using good programming practices, you use quotation marks (these " and these ') Indiscriminately. You should only alternate between them when you have them nested.
Next, on the action paramenter you should put the name of the file, even if it's the same.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions on programming style, I would try to improve. But I don think that its the issue here. Also I gave the name of the file in action and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have two submit buttons?

Comment: My application requires so one to search and one to clear